# Google search results snippet for our site is a warning about not being able to play HTML5 video

Tags: seo, google-search, html5

All of a sudden, without any change in the `index.html`, our site is showing up in Google search results (on multiple browsers and devices) with Google Preview text that, instead of giving a summary of our site, now says:

> Your browser does not currently recognize any of the video formats available. Click here to visit our frequently asked questions about HTML5 video.

[image]

We have a YouTube embed on our homepage that does include an html5 parameter in the media URL link in the embed, but there are no issues playing the video with any browser and device we can find.

What would suddenly cause this text to appear in Google search results?

We are using the [Open Graph](http://ogp.me/#) tags as the metatags in the `<head>` of our webpage and do indeed have title and description tags.

To mimic the behavior of Googlebot, I installed Windows on a VM and got Chromium 41 running. I get the same Google Preview text with the html5 video message when the site comes up in Google search results using this browser.

When I view the site in Chromium 41, I see the YouTube embed and it renders on the page and plays with no issue, just as with all other browser and devices we've tested on. The only time we see this message is in the Google search results, not on our actual site.

Comment: It is not just a problem with your site.  Take a look at these search results:  https://www.google.com/search?tbs=li:1&q=%22Your+browser+does+not+currently+recognize+any+of+the+video+formats+available.+Click+here+to+visit+our+frequently+asked+questions+about+HTML5+video%22

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for sharing that. I shudder to think what our site has in common with all these weird, geocities-esque looking sites. Something must be in serious need of an update on our index.html I would think.

Comment: This question is now a year old without any answers.   We've had three people drop by to comment that they have the same issue.  There are also now threads in Google Search Console help about this issue: https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/27737765?hl=en and https://support.google.com/webmasters/thread/13071000?hl=en  neither of which has a solution.

Comment: Do you find the answer? I'm haveing the same problem with one of my friend

Answer (score 1):

This is my guess, but this sounds like it's simply a video codec issue. Do your youtube videos use h264, webm or something else? Your videos would play fine on your computer and on your personal browser if you had the codecs installed separately to decode the videos. Only Firefox and Opera according to the HTML5 video page have built in decoding for HTML5 video.